# Pylance does not allow me to navigate to the source code, bringing me to the .pyi stub instead

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using pylance for vs code and it works really nice, except that since I use it, when I try to check code from an installed library, I can get only to the stub, I think generated by pylance.

For example, the information shown about the function:
[image]

Or, crtl + click on the function brings me to the .pyi stub, which at
`~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2020.11.0/dist/bundled/stubs/pandas/io/parsers.pyi`

I can't find a way to navigate to the actual code (of pandas in this case).

If I deactivate Pylance and use Microsoft as language server by setting `"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",` in setting.json, the navigation to the library works fine.

Is it possible to navigate to the actual code with pylance active?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Visual Studio Code: Version: 1.50.1
Pylance: v2020.11.0

Comment: if PyLance behaves worse compared to Microsoft LS file an issue at PyLance

Comment: Maybe there is a way to configure it that I was not able to find. Otherwise maybe if there isn't or if it is too convoluted I could consider filing an issue.

Comment: these run time generated functions do not have a nice definition and doc string. By using these stub files they present these to the user

Comment: "Microsoft" doesn't show up as an option for me. Any idea why?

Comment: In the end what worked for me, after trying everything else, was invalidating the cache. Hope this is useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and realized I was using Docker. So I set up virtualenv and installed Django using pip.
Then I switched Python interpreter in the bottom-left corner of VS Code and it started working.

I know this is a specific case but I hope this answer helps someone in the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's remove `~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2020.11.0/dist/bundled/stubs/pandas`

Then reload vscode

Comment: Didn't work for me. I also tried deleting `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.1.40/dist/bundled/stubs/django-stubs` and then "Go to Definition" doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

When I select the right python interpreter, i navigate to the src code not .pyi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved the problem by manually selecting right interpreter in vscode footer bar.

Answer (score -1):

You can navigate to the references by right-clicking on the symbol and selecting "Go to References".

Also, ensure that you have a `Python interpreter` configured for the script where pandas is installed.

You can select an interpreter by opening `Command Palette` from the `View` menu and typing in "Python: Select Interpreter" and following through the dialog.

When you have that set, you should see two references when you Ctrl + click on a symbol: one for the stub and the other from the library.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately, it does not work for me (https://imgur.com/rnQ84SN). I select the interpreter and in "Peek definition" only the .pyi appears. The code runs fine with Ctrl+F5 so Pandas is there.