# How to configure Microsoft Pylance to not use stub files (.pyi) for django?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am doing Django development using visual studio code on mac os with microsoft's pylance extension installed. Following is the version specification of my eco system :

```
OS -> MacOS Mojave
django -> 3.1.5
visual studio code -> 1.52.1
Microsoft Pylance -> 2021.1.2 Release (latest)
```

We use JSONField from django's 3.1.5 version.
Pylance use stub files for django located at
`extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.1.2/dist/bundled/stubs/djano/db/models/__init__.pyi`

[image]

I can clearly see that stubs file mentioned is not up-to-date. Because of that, vscode is not able to resolve reference to `models.JSONField`.
While for other libraries like `jsonschema` , it simply relies on their `__init__.py`. That's what I want.

[image]

I checked what all can be configured on official page of `Pylance` but I did not find any suitable configuraiton.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

I am considering following options :

1. Delete stubs file/directory for django, I don't know what will be repercussions.
2. Manually setting `python.analysis.extraPaths` to my virtualenv path.

I am looking for a more organic solution and I'll provide the result of the above experiments in the comments.

Thanks !

Comment: Option 1 works. I have deleted django from `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.1.2/dist/bundled/stubs/django` and it started paying respect to django it deserves ! :)

Comment: since you have a workaround, `I suggest you could add it as answer rather than a comment, and then mark your own answer.` I could help other community members search and handle similar issues:) Thanks in advanced!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64701174/pylance-does-not-allow-me-to-navigate-to-the-source-code-bringing-me-to-the-py/71806760#71806760

Comment: @UtsavChokshi didn't work for me. The "Go to Definition" feature just stopped working altogether :(